# artifactory gradle plugin overwrite snapshot versions

Tags: maven, gradle, plugins, artifactory

I would like to publish artefacts on my local Artifactory instance, with annotated Artifactory metatada, and with a version number based on a time-stamp for SNAPSHOT artefacts versions.

I tried to use the artifactory gradle plugin and the maven-publish plugin for this purpose.

However, it is (as far as I know) not possible to annotate Artifactory metadata while using the maven-publish plugin.

And if I use the artifactory gradle plugin, I get an error "Not enough permissions to overwrite artifact ..." while publishing two different SNAPSHOT versions of a given artefact.

In fact, the *artifactoryPublish* task tries to overwrite the existent artefact, instead of using a time-stamp.

To be noticed that my Artifactory repository is correctly set-up (Version number is based on a time-stamp). Thus, no errors are raised if I use the maven-publish plugin (the artefacts are published with a time-stamp, and no overwritting is done).

Is someone familiar with these issues?

I used a project example available here:
https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples/4/gradle-example-minimal

Which I modified a bit to adapt it to my local configuration.

I am using the following artifactory plugin:
org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle-uber:4.4.14

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing the same issues, the problem was the repository layout definition. I have to use the *maven-2-default* layout definition to publish SNAPSHOT artefacts versions with timestamps and artifactory properties.